# How to write a SQL update statement that will fail if it updates more than one row?

Tags: sql

A common mistake when writing update statements is to forget the where clause, or to write it incorrectly, so that more rows than expected get updated. Is there a way to specify **in the update statement itself** that it should only update one row (and to fail if it would update more)?

Correcting an error in the number of rows updated requires thinking ahead - using a transaction, formatting it as a select first to check the number of rows - and then actually catching the error. It would be useful to be able to write in one place the expectation for the number of rows.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ? The number of rows updated by an `UPDATE` statement depends on the conditions specified in the `WHERE` clause. To ensure that **only one row** is updated, you can include conditions in the `WHERE` clause that uniquely identify the row you want to update. For example, you could use the primary key of the table in the `WHERE` clause to update a single row. If you want to fail the `UPDATE` statement if it would update more than one row, you can use the `LIMIT` clause that is available in some DBMS.
`UPDATE table SET column = value WHERE condition LIMIT 1;`

Comment: You could also issue a SELECT statement prior to the UPDATE to determine how many records would get updated.  Or wrap your UPDATE in a Transaction and verify the number of rows updated, then rollback the transaction if it exceeds 1

Comment: Yes, both of those techniques work, but they require more manual work while executing the update statement, and there are more ways to fail.

Comment: Even if you could (for example, in SQL Server you can use the TOP clause when deleting, inserting, updating) - if you had that set to always be TOP 1, but then you'd inadvertently made your WHERE clause incorrect, the result of the UPDATE is going to say that "1 row was updated" ..... you're then going to be happy with that?  You seem to be wanting to circumvent some important validation that can really only be done by physically confirming results of a SELECT and then a corresponding UPDATE (that applies the same WHERE clause, etc., as the SELECT)

Comment: @najx I'm using Postgres but solutions for other dbs would be helpful too.

Regarding crafting the `where` clause to match only one row - I'm looking for a way to catch _mistakes_ in the where clause; the intent is to match exactly one row and the where clause should already be written to attempt that.

Comment: You can use stored procedures in which the necessary checks are performed. At the same time prohibiting the use of simple update operations. / Also you can use triggers. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8607

Answer (score 1):

Combining a few facts, I found a working solution for Postgres.

1. A `select` will fail when comparing using = to a subquery that returns more than one row. (`where x = (select ...)`)
2. Values can be returned from an update statement, using the `returning` clause. An update cannot be used as a subquery, but it *can* be used as a CTE, which can be used in a subquery.

Example:

```
create table foo (id int not null primary key, x int not null);
insert into foo (id, x) values (1,5), (2,5);

with updated as (update foo set x = 4 where x = 5 returning id)
select id from foo where id = (select id from updated);
```

The query containing the update fails with `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`, and the updates are not applied. If the update's `where` clause is adjusted to only match one row, the update succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You might do this:

```
UPDATE foo SET x = '4' WHERE x = '5'
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE x = '5') <= 1;
```

In other words:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET column = new_value
WHERE your_condition
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE your_condition) <= 1;
```